# Main DC is no longer NTP or hold FSMOs

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, ntp, domain-controller

Good Afternoon,

We two virtual DC and one local physical read only DC.  When we moved our data center offsite with a warm backup site we p to v our DC’s and DC1 was the master schema.
While troubleshooting another issue we found an issue with our Main DC (DC1). When I was attempting to modify a group policy it gave me an error and could not find our domain.

When I check the Operational Master is stated ERROR and list (DC1). When I run a netdom querry fismo the result points to (DC2). On DC2, the Operation Master is DC2.

When I ran a dcdiag on dc1:

`Directory Server Diagnosis`

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = AOBVADC001
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Col-DC\AOBVADC001
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... AOBVADC001 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Col-DC\AOBVADC001
      Starting test: Advertising
         Warning: AOBVADC001 is not advertising as a time server.
         ......................... AOBVADC001 failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.

Running enterprise tests on : swaco.org
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         Warning: DcGetDcName(PDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355
         A Primary Domain Controller could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355
         A Time Server could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error
         1355
         A Good Time Server could not be located.
         ......................... swaco.org failed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... swaco.org passed test Intersite

On the second DC the dcdaig

`Directory Server Diagnosis`

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = AOBVADC002
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Col-DC\AOBVADC002
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... AOBVADC002 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Col-DC\AOBVADC002
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... AOBVADC002 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.
      Starting test: SystemLog
Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x000016AF
            Time Generated: 11/25/2014   08:15:40
            Event String:
            During the past 4.24 hours there have been 145 connections to this D
omain Controller from client machines whose IP addresses don't map to any of the
 existing sites in the enterprise. Those clients, therefore, have undefined site
s and may connect to any Domain Controller including those that are in far dista
nt locations from the clients. A client's site is determined by the mapping of i
ts subnet to one of the existing sites. To move the above clients to one of the
sites, please consider creating subnet object(s) covering the above IP addresses
 with mapping to one of the existing sites.  The names and IP addresses of the c
lients in question have been logged on this computer in the following log file '
%SystemRoot%\debug\netlogon.log' and, potentially, in the log file '%SystemRoot%
\debug\netlogon.bak' created if the former log becomes full. The log(s) may cont
ain additional unrelated debugging information. To filter out the needed informa
tion, please search for lines which contain text 'NO_CLIENT_SITE:'. The first wo
rd after this string is the client name and the second word is the client IP add
ress. The maximum size of the log(s) is controlled by the following registry DWO
RD value 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Paramete
rs\LogFileMaxSize'; the default is 20000000 bytes.  The current maximum size is
20000000 bytes.  To set a different maximum size, create the above registry valu
e and set the desired maximum size in bytes.
        ......................... AOBVADC002 failed test SystemLog

I believe I know what I need to do with DC1, but have not done this since College.

I believe I will have dcpromo down DC1, then dcpromo back up. If I want I can transfer FSMO back to DC1, but really I don't care.

Any thoughts on my issue?

Comment: Shameless marketing: You're well within driving distance for me. >smile< I'd be more than happy to negotiate the terms of an on-site visit.

Comment: @EvanAnderson unless you know this man already, I'm scared to think how you deduced his location with the information given.  Are you secretly running anon without our knowledge?

Comment: How did you p2v DC1?

Comment: @Greg Askew Our previous System Administration did the migration to the two data center.  There are a ton  of products like VMware that can do this http://www.vmware.com/products/converter.

Comment: I was more interested in the details.  There is definitely some caveats with the process.

Comment: @Greg Askew.  Before our Sys Admin left he did have a bear of a time making this happen.  I wish I can give you more details but I had no part of that process.   I know he was frustrated enough to consider just creating a new VM at the site.

Comment: Were the resulting VMs from the P2V run in an isolated environment, or were they able to communicate to the existing network? (I feel like, if it were a disaster recovery exercise, they would be run in an isolated environment. That would be the norm, at least.)

Comment: @EvanAnderson We migrated just couple months ago and we doing a full DR Drill around Christmas.  We have two 100GB pipes to the data center here in Columbus and the backup site in Cleveland.  We migrated the DCs one at a time.  We did have the change the ip addressing with help of a Cisco Engineer that design the new network.  It was almost a seamless process with the exception of the former SYS ADMIN convert those DC's.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you've got a DNS problem. I don't think there's anything FSMO-related really happening. Start by making sure that the AOBVADC001 machine is getting good DNS resolution for the domain.

Comment: I not seeing the DNS issue because I can ping from the main DC AOBVADC001 to outside and inside the organization.  NSLOOKKUP are resolving as well for inside and outside.

Comment: It still sounds like a DNS problem to me. What does the output for `nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.swaco.org` look like on the `AOBVADC001` machine? What DNS servers are specified on that machine?

Comment: You correct.  Non-existent domain.  I ran that on DC2 and same the results.  The DNS server are the ip address 10.101.9.30 (DC1) and 10.101.9.40 (DC2).

Comment: Thx for you help.  I now gotta figure out how this happen.  I was not thinking DNS when ping, tracert, and the basic nslookup commands did not error out.

Comment: @JamesO'Keeffe - You may well have been getting broadcast NetBIOS name resolution when you tried those commands.

Comment: I was still baffled and looked the GUI and found that service record where it should be. I ran it again

Comment: On DC1 it showing aobvadc001.swaco.org, 10.101.9.30

Comment: On DC2 it showing aobvadc002.swaco.org 10.101.9.40.  I must of fat fingered it.

Comment: The resulting SRV record returned by that `nslookup` should be the same regardless of which DNS server you run it against. That's the query to located the PDC Emulator FSMO role-holder. If you're seeing different results for that `nslookup` run against different DNS servers then you've got an Active Directory replication problem (because, likely, you're using Active Directory-integrated DNS zones).

Comment: I ran some repadmin cmds and at first found no issues.  The queue aand showrepl did not find any issues.  However, on DC1, when I use the /syncall  two objects failed: error issueing replication 8453 (0x2105).  The rabbit hole just got bigger.  I'm try find this error technet